# How to use first select query's result in second query as column in stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I have an issue in stored procedure.

In my stored procedure code the first query returning the columns which will be use in second query as select column but instead of providing value of the columns it showing the columns in result.
Please tell me, what I am doing wrong

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `database`.`getProcedure`(
        id int(11),
        reportType varchar(20),
        tableName varchar(30),
        startDate varchar(30),
        endDate varchar(30)
    )
BEGIN

    SET @lead = (SELECT CONCAT('SUM(',GROUP_CONCAT('`',CONCAT(tableName,'`.`',`table2`.`database_field`) SEPARATOR "`+"),'`)')
    FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2
    ON table2.id = table1.attribute_id 
    WHERE table1.id = id;
     
    SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT(table1.c1)) AS `c1`, 
        sum(table1.c2) AS `c2`,
        sum(table1.c3) AS `c3`, 
        sum(table1.c4) AS `c4`,
        @lead AS `c5`
   FROM table3 
   LEFT JOIN table4 ON table3.id = table4.table3_id
   WHERE (table3.id = id 
   AND table3.date >= startDate 
   AND table3.date <= endDate);
END
```

Showing result in c5 is SUM(`table3`.`c6`+`table3`.`c7`+`table3`.`c8`)

but result should be the value of SUM(`table3`.`c6`+`table3`.`c7`+`table3`.`c8`)

Comment: I've removed the [[tag:sql-server]] tag, is this is clearly *not T-SQL. I can't comment if the other 2 tags aren't relevant.

Comment: The task is absolutely unclear. Create online fiddle with your structures/data and show desired output with detailed explanations.

Comment: You'd need to construct the 2nd query as a string, and then executed that string using the prepared statement / execute functions.

Right now you are passing in the result variable from the first query and that's just interpreted as "use the current value of this variable as a constant result value", not as a column name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Hartmut Holzgraefe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73121825/how-to-use-first-select-querys-result-in-second-query-as-column-in-stored-proce?noredirect=1#comment129166976_73121825) commented, the solution is

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `database`.`getProcedure`(
    id int(11),
    reportType varchar(20),
    tableName varchar(30),
    startDate varchar(30),
    endDate varchar(30)
)
BEGIN
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT CONCAT('SUM(',GROUP_CONCAT('`',CONCAT(tableName,'`.`',`table2`.`database_field`) SEPARATOR "`+"),'`)') as @sql
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table2.id = table1.attribute_id 
WHERE table1.id = id;
 
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(table1.c1)) AS `c1`, 
    sum(table1.c2) AS `c2`,
    sum(table1.c3) AS `c3`, 
    sum(table1.c4) AS `c4`,',
    @sql,' AS `c5`
FROM table3 
LEFT JOIN table4 ON table3.id = table4.table3_id
WHERE (table3.id = ',id,' 
AND table3.date >= "',startDate,'" 
AND table3.date <= "',endDate,'");');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```